# Adding Marker to Google Maps in google-map-react

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, meteor, google-maps-api-3

I am using the [`google-map-react`](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) NPM package to create a Google Map and several markers.

**Question:** How can we add the default Google Maps markers to the map?

[From this Github issue](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react/issues/173), it seems that we need to access the internal Google Maps API using the [onGoogleApiLoaded](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react#ongoogleapiloaded-func) function.

Referring to [an example from the Google Maps JS API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), we can use the following code to render the marker, but how do we define the references to `map`?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

**Current Code:**

```
renderMarkers() {
    ...
}

render() {
    return (
        <div style={{'width':800,'height':800}}>
            <GoogleMap
                bootstrapURLKeys={{key: settings.googleMapApiKey}}
                defaultZoom={13}
                defaultCenter={{ 
                    lat: this.props.user.profile.location.coordinates[1], 
                    lng: this.props.user.profile.location.coordinates[0]
                }}
                onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => this.renderMarkers()}
                yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
            >
            </GoogleMap>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit:**
Since this answer was posted the docs (and likely, the API) of the `GoogleMapReact` element was changed to support children. Any child with `lat` and `lng` would be rendered at the corresponding location on the map, as also indicated by @Jobsamuel's answer.

The `onGoogleApiLoaded` callback should not be used for this purpose, as it is inferior to the declarative style and would not be re-run if changes are made to the map.

---

Original answer (outdated):

This may not be entirely clear from the description in the Readme, but the `maps` argument is, in fact, the maps API object (and `map` is, of course, the current Google Map instance). Therefore, you should pass both to your method:

```
onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => this.renderMarkers(map, maps)}
```

and use them:

```
renderMarkers(map, maps) {
  let marker = new maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}
```

Comment: do you also know how to add the `infowindow`? I am having difficulties implementing this

Comment: I have really used the raw Maps API with this package, but rather the declarative React API. Doesn't the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) on Google's API documentation work for you? If not, you should probably create a new question with your code and explanations.

Comment: how would you re-render the marker every time the map changes?

Comment: is their a demo

Answer (score 20):

Adding a marker on your map isn't as easy as we would like to, mostly because the [confusing docs](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react) but here you have a super easy example:

```
const Map = props => {
  return (
    <GoogleMapReact
     bootstrapURLKeys={{ props.key }}
     defaultCenter={{lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng}}
     defaultZoom={props.zoom}>

       {/* This is the missing part in docs:
         *
         * Basically, you only need to add a Child Component that
         * takes 'lat' and 'lng' Props. And that Component should
         * returns a text, image, super-awesome-pin (aka, your marker).
         *
         */}
       <Marker lat={props.lat} lng={props.lng}} />
    </GoogleMapReact>
  )
}

const Marker = props => {
  return <div className="SuperAwesomePin"></div>
}
```

Comment: Can you post your SuperAwesomePin class?

Comment: How do you import `Marker`?

Comment: @ben.coffee you don't need to. `Marker` is just a custom Component. Something like `const Marker = props => <div className="pin"></div>`

Comment: here you have @newman https://gist.github.com/jobsamuel/56496033bfb4d0f3e316aeb88341ed16 (Sorry for the ultra-super-mega late answer)

Comment: I am finding it confusing since typescript forcing me to add lat lng prop to the market component but then it does not work that way either..

Answer (score 15):

Looking in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react), it mentions 'You can access to Google Maps map and maps objects by using onGoogleApiLoaded, in this case you will need to set yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals to true', this helped me with the code below.

```
import React from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const GoogleMaps = ({ latitude, longitude }) => {
 const renderMarkers = (map, maps) => {
  let marker = new maps.Marker({
  position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
  map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  return marker;
 };

 return (
   <div style={{ height: '50vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'YOUR KEY' }}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: latitude, lng: longitude }}
      defaultZoom={16}
      yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
      onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => renderMarkers(map, maps)}
    >
    </GoogleMapReact>
   </div>
 );
};

export default GoogleMaps;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by [MasterAM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41406842/4334913).

If you using react hooks, this one could do the trick:

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';

const createControlledPromise = () => {
  let resolver;
  let rejector;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolver = resolve;
    rejector = reject;
  });
  return { promise, resolver, rejector };
};

const useMarker = ({ lat, lng }) => {
  const { 
    promise: apiPromise, 
    resolver: handleGoogleApiLoaded 
  } = useMemo(
    createControlledPromise,
    []
  ).current;

  useEffect(
    () => {
      let marker;
      apiPromise.then(api => {
        const { map, maps } = api;
        marker = new maps.Marker({ position: { lat, lng }, map });
      });
      return () => {
        if (marker) {
          marker.setMap(null);
        }
      };
    },
    [lat, lon],
  );
  return { handleGoogleApiLoaded };
};

const Location = ({
  location: { locationName, lat, lng }
}) => {
  const { handleGoogleApiLoaded } = useMarker({ lat, lng });
  return (
    <section>
      <h1>{locationName}</h1>
      <p>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: __GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY__ }}
          center={{ lat, lng }}
          defaultZoom={11}
          onGoogleApiLoaded={handleGoogleApiLoaded}
        />
      </p>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention. Note that the API/docs have changed to support children. See my edit for more details.