# Default marker as function component

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

Using this [Google Map lib](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react), from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405343/adding-marker-to-google-maps-in-google-map-react), I can create a default marker on the map. However, this onGoogleApiLoaded() will only be fired once. I wanted to always center marker on the map. But default marker will required a position at the minimum, so I am trying create the default marker as function and pass new position into it but I couldn't make it work.

I have a main component which will render the the MapContainer component.

```
Main.js:

const { defaultCenter, defaultZoom, div_Height, div_Width, newCenter } = this.state;

return(
        <div style={{width: 500, height: 100}}>
            <div>          
                <MapContainer
                defaultCenter={defaultCenter}
                defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onClick={this.onClick}
                div_Height={div_Height}
                div_Width={div_Width}
                newCenter={newCenter}>

                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
```

and a onChange function to get new center coords.

```
onChange(center){
    let {newCenter} = this.state;
    newCenter = center.center;
    this.setState({newCenter})
}
```

In my MapContainer which to render the GoogleMap:

```
MapContainer:

const { defaultCenter, defaultZoom, onChange, onClick} = this.props;
let {newCenter} = this.props
const {apiReady, map, maps} = this.state;

return (
  // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
  <div style={{height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
    <GoogleMapReact
      /*bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'key' }}*/
      defaultCenter={defaultCenter}
      defaultZoom={defaultZoom}
      yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
      onGoogleApiLoaded={({map, maps}) => this.apiLoaded(map, maps)} 
      onClick={onClick}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
    {apiReady ? <Marker map={map} maps={maps} newCenter={newCenter}/>: null}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  </div>
);
```

onGoogleApiLoaded func to set the map, maps:

```
apiLoaded(map, maps) {
if (map && maps) {
 this.setState({
   apiReady: true,
   map: map,
   maps: maps
 });
 }}
```

And lastly the way I create the marker:

```
const Marker = (props) => {
  return (new props.maps.Marker({
    position: props.newCenter,
    map: props.map
  }));   
}
```

The error I get is: 
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {__gm, gm_accessors_, position, gm_bindings_, map, closure_uid_621320123, clickable, visible}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130539/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string)

Comment: I tried to look at it and test some solutions but still not able to make it. Can you point out some hints on where you think that is 'duplicated' to that question? @ShireeshaParampalli