# Adding Marker to Google Maps in google-map-react with functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am using the [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) NPM package to create a Google Map and several markers.
The information for the coordinates, infowindow, icon, etc. will come from a JSON file.
I have added onGoogleApiLoaded and yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals.

This is what my code currently looks like, with the markers being inside this file for the time being

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react'

let mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 39.56939, lng: -40.0000 },
    zoom: 3.5,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    gestureHandling: 'none',
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    panControl: false,
  };
function ModelsMap({ data, state }) {

    console.log(data.models)

    function initMap() {

        let markers = [
         /.../
        ];

        function Marker(props) {

            let marker = new google.maps.marker({
                position: props.coords,
                content: props.content,
                icon: props.icon,
                map: map
            });

            let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: props.content
            });

            Marker.addListener('click', function () {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            })
        }
    }
     // useEffect(initMap, []); it will only render once 
    return (
        <div style={{height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
            <GoogleMapReact
                bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "YOUR_API_KEY" }}
                defaultCenter={{lat: 39.56939, lng: -40.0000 }}
                defaultZoom={3.5}
                options={mapOptions}
                yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
                onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => ModelsMap(map, maps)}
                >
                
            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ModelsMap;
```

I have followed the solution listed on [This other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405343/adding-marker-to-google-maps-in-google-map-react), but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the answers on the StackOverflow you provided they uses `new maps.Marker()` to create a new Google Maps marker. If you want to get the value of your coordinates,icons and different properties of marker from a json data, you need to put this `new maps.Marker()` to loop through each json data. Below should be the value of your `ModelsMap`. Don't for get to import your json file.

```
const ModelsMap = (map, maps) => {
    //instantiate array that will hold your Json Data
    let dataArray = [];
    //push your Json Data in the array
    {
      data.map((markerJson) => dataArray.push(markerJson));
    }

    //Loop through the dataArray to create a marker per data using the coordinates in the json
    for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      let marker = new maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: dataArray[i].lat, lng: dataArray[i].lng },
        map,
        label: dataArray[i].id,
      });
    }
  };
```

Here is a [sample code that shows this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/looping-through-json-data-google-map-react-rgrxra?file=Map.js). Please use your own API key for this to work.

Side Note: I removed the API Key in your question. Please don't share your API keys in public sites in the future.

Answer (score 0):

enable javascript map api from your google cloud console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).